# Specify interaction effetcs in Random Forest and Neural Network

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, interaction

I would like to realize a predictive model (Random forest or Neural network) with 8 variables, considering for each the interaction effect with other three variables. 
I'm using `caret` package and I wanna know have I to specify the interaction terms? like below:

```
model <-y~a*x1*x2*x3+b*x1*x2*x3+c*x1*x2*x3+d*x1*x2*x3+e*x1*x2*x3+f*x1*x2*x3+g*x1*x2*x3+h*x1*x2*x3,method="nnet",returnData=TRUE,
      trControl= trainControl(
     method = "rf", number = 10,
        verboseIter = TRUE,savePredictions = TRUE
      ), importance=T
    )
```

[where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h are my eight input variables and x1,x2 and x3 the interaction terms]

or using machine learning method is it not necessary specify the interaction because this type of methods don't have any kind of assumpiont?

Comment: These types of models probe interaction by default. No need (and no way) to specify it.

Comment: So as you say, I have to add the three variables to the other eight, like input variables?

Comment: Yes, i get it! But I have to add in someway the three variables, because these are not included in the eight variables.

Comment: Are the 8 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) variables numerical while the x1 - x3 are categorical? I think some additional context would be nice. In general just separate all variables with a `+` and that's it.

Comment: All variables are numerical, both (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) and x1-x3